# How to convert to uppercase the second and penultimate letter of a string list in Python using a lambda function and return a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have this code but it is returning the first letter. I need the second and penultimate letter to be uppercase

```
def first_last_uppercase(array):
  serie = pd.Series(array)
  return serie.map(lambda x: x[0].upper() + x[1:-1] + x[-1].upper())

first_last_uppercase(languages)
```

Actual result:

```
0        PythoN
1           PhP
2          JavA
3    JavascripT
4           C++
5           SqL
```

Expected result:

```
0        pYthOn
1           pHp
2          jAVa
3    jAvascriPt
4           c++
5           sQl
```

any idea

Comment: Are we doing your homework for you?

Answer (score 1):

Remember Python is 0-indexed, so the 2nd element is `1`. The last element of an iterable is `-1`, so the second-to-last is `-2`. So, modify your return statement to say

```
return serie.map(lambda x: x[0] + x[1].upper() + x[2:-2] + x[-2].upper() + x[-1])
```

It's a little bulky, but I think it works for your input:

```
>>> x = ["python", "php", "java", "javascript", "c++", "sql"]
>>> serie = pd.Series(x)
>>> serie.map(lambda x: x[0] + x[1].upper() + x[2:-2] + x[-2].upper() + x[-1])
0        pYthOn
1          pHHp
2          jAVa
3    jAvascriPt
4          c+++
5          sQQl
```

Wait, it returned `pHHp`, `c+++`, and `sQQl` for `"php"`, `"c++"`, and `"sql"`, respectively. If I try a 2-character string, like `"c#"`, I get `"c#C#"`. And if I try giving it just a single letter, like `"c"`, it dies with an `IndexError`.

You need to check the length of the string before you pass it to the lambda, which would be completely unreadable if you tried to put it *all* in a single lambda. Instead, define a function and use that.

```
def two_caps(thing: str) -> str:
    if len(thing) > 3:
        new_thing = thing[0] + thing[1].upper() + thing[2:-2] + thing[-2].upper() + thing[-1]
    elif len(thing) == 3:
        new_thing = thing[0] + thing[1].upper() + thing[2]
    else:
        new_thing = thing
    return new_thing
```

This returns properly-capitalized strings for inputs >= 3. If the `len()` is < 3, it returns the original thing. Now you can use this return statement:

```
return serie.Map(lambda x: two_caps(x))
```

and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Use `capitalize` and slice the middle part with `1:-2` to get an empty string when the input is short.

```
def first_last_uppercase(array):
  serie = pd.Series(array)
  return serie.map(lambda x: x[0].lower() + x[1:-2].capitalize() + x[max(1,len(x)-2):].capitalize())

a = ["python", "c", "c#", "php", "java", "javascript", "c++", "sql"]
first_last_uppercase(a)
```

Output:

```
0        pYthOn
1             c
2            c#
3           pHp
4          jAVa
5    jAvascriPt
6           c++
7           sQl
dtype: object
```

Comment: This still has the same problems that I described in my answer with 2- and 1-letter strings. `"c#"` returns as `"cC#"` and `"c"` returns as `"cC"`. That's why you need to do length testing. Granted, it's not clear from the question what exactly should be done with strings with length > 3, but I'm pretty sure the solution isn't to add letters to the string in the process.

Comment: @MattDMo see update